# UIautomation on windows: How to get element name of window element (zoom audio icon)

Tags: windows, winapi, ui-automation, user32, microsoft-ui-automation

**I want to detect the user name and mute icon using windows uiautomation on zoom meeting window**

[image]

**Inspect Tool on windows does not show any thing related to this icon and user name...**

[image]

**How can I find that icon type(window, button, tool tip) or better complete user name and icon...**
**Is there any other tool to find these things?**

Comment: Unless the application provides a custom automation interface, there's no way to query for information that's not accessible through UI Automation.